# Do I need to render the fat from the edge of a steak if I'm cooking it in a George Foreman type grill?

Tags: steak

I'm familiar with rendering the edge fat of a piece of meat, but I don't know if that's necessary if I'm cooking it in a George Foreman type grill, with plates either side.

Obviously it depends on the cut and the amount of fat, but how do I know when it needs separate rendering before grilling?

Comment: You can always trim off the fat instead of eating it.  Trying to cook the edge would defeat the convenience of that style of appliance

Comment: @Joe I can use the grill like a traditional griddle which is still more convenient for me. But if I know how much fat would be rendered just by putting it in the grill, without trimming/separate rendering that would be handy.

Answer (score 2):

Steak cooks relatively quickly. You are not going to get much rendering. (Maybe you are not using the term correctly?  Rendering is slowing cooking so that most of the fat liquefies...generally not what you are after when cooking a steak). So, it depends on your personal preference of how much fat you like on your grilled steak (some of this also depends on the steak quality and fat content). As @Joe points out, trimming some or most fat before cooking is a good option.  Searing the edges and sides on the grill or flat top, is really just for coloring, light crisping, or charring, rather than for rendering.  In a steak preparation, one is either going to eat that fat or trim it off while eating, depending on your preference.  On the other hand, for example, when cooking duck breast, one generally wants the fat between the skin and meat to render out.

Comment: Perhaps rendering isn't the right term. I want the fat to not be chewy basically.